# Trying to change image "title" tag on logo on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, seo

I'm trying to change the image "title" tag on the upper left logo of this website: http://bodenkraft.com but I can't for the life of me find where it can be changed. I have looked up how to enable alt and title tags within content types but this logo doesn't seem to correspond to any content type and I couldn't find any information on how to change them once they are already uploaded.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the logo printed in the page.tpl.php file of the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo of the site code can be found in the enabled theme folder. Inside theme folder there will be a templates folder and there will be a file names page.tpl where you can find the html for the logo and you can add title to that image tag.

I hope it helps.